# Error con requests.post, ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, post, flask

Hola tengo un error cuando intento pasar unas imágenes a mi servidor flask de un diccionario mientras las leo y guardo como una tupla

```
import requests as RQ

dd = {
    'img' : ['a.jpg','b.jpg','c.jpg','d.jpg','e.jpg']
}

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:/8070/img_d'

#convierto el diccionario en una tupla   
mul_img = []

for v, k in enumerate(dd):
    a = dd.get(k)
    for i, e in enumerate(a):
        n = (open(e, 'rb'))
        mul_img.append(n)
        Res = RQ.post(url, files=mul_img[i])
```

Error

> for (k, v) in files: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected
> 2)

¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: No me ha dado ningún error :/

Comment: **for (k, v) in files:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)** me aparece este error cuando intento ejecutarla:(